# Dual boot with Ubuntu

Tags: windows-10, dualboot

I am very new to Linux
I have an existing Windows 10 Pro PC
I added Ubuntu 22.04 as a dual boot.
Windows 10 pro and the ubuntu are on separate drives.

If I go into the Bios I can switch drives to boot to either OS.
both OS's will run correctly at this point.

When I Boot to Ubuntu I get the option to boot to my windows 10
Windows 10 (on /dev/sda1)

But if I boot to the windows 10 i get the following error.
setting partition type to 0x7
error: cant find command 'drivemap'
error: invalid EFI file path

Press any key to continue
which brings me back to the boot select screen.

I did notice that the boot drive for windows 10 is on sda2
How would I change this?

I did follow the suggestions above but it did not fix the issue, so I kept digging .
I finally Found the issue.   Turns out it was a bios issue.
The AHCI only showed the Windows installation, but when I dug deaper
I noticed under advanced boot options it gave me a secondary AHCI boot partition.
Once I changed the boot menu to use the secondary boot it gave me the option to select between the 2 OS’s

Thank you for the help and ideas.
It did help a lot in troubleshooting the issue.

Comment: Can you boot into Windows? If you can, turn off Windows fast startup.

Comment: ... and then boot Ubuntu and run `sudo update-grub`. Report back and make sure to [edit] the question accordingly.

Comment: I disabled the fast start and restarted Ubuntu.  Now i don't get the option to boot into windows.  I comes up with the following error then completes booting Ubuntu.       2.586134]  ucsi_ccg 0-0008: failed to get FW build information     3.586561] nvidia-gpu 000:1c:00.3:  i2c timeout error e0000000     3.586603] ucsi_ccg 0-0008: ucsi_ccg_trandfer failed - -110     3.586631 ucsi-ccg 0-0008: ucsi_ccg_init failed - -110     /dev/sdb6: clean, 218189/183578624 files, 15172521/1468618496 blocks

Comment: if i go into Bios i can still boot to either one

Comment: @Elohssa [Edit] your question instead of submitting unformatted commentary.  Have you considered using a VM or WSL instead of trying to dual boot Linux? How did you determine Windows is on sda2 instead of sda1?

Comment: Did you run the command above? If so what were the results? Full error or other messages, please. And again, [edit] your question, not just comments.